# Why is the pipeline not triggered after I push the yml file?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I created a .gitlab-ci.yml file on master branch to create a mkdocs static site for my respository. But everytime I commit something, the pipeline is not reacting. Any ideas why this happens?

Here is the .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: python:latest
pages:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - pip install mkdocs-material
    - mkdocs build --site-dir public
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
```

Comment: what's the result if you manually trigger the pipeline?

Comment: ‘_everytime I commit something_’ You push it too, right?

Comment: Even when I manually trigger the pipeline by changing the yml file, nothing happens. Yes, I also push it to the repository and I can also see it on gitlab

Comment: is `.gitlab-ci.yml` in git root?

Comment: Are you running manually against or pushing some commits to the `master` branch?

Comment: What are your settings if you go to [project] > Settings > CI/CD > CI/CD configuration file? (https://gitlab.example.com/web/MY_PROJECT/-/settings/ci_cd) Make sure the file path is correct